# How one could imagine the angular momentum of a free particle in the quantum mechanical view?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

According the inertia principle, a free particle has only a straight trajectory, thus it couldn't have an angular momentum different from zero. In the quantum mechanical view, the free particle could have any value of angular momentum. Thus, the particle could have a quantized rotations but it is hard for me to imagine these rotations for a free particle ? When the angular momentum is zero, we can imagine the classical view according to inertia principle but a non zero value is hard to imagine ?

Comment: 1. *"thus it couldn't have an angular momentum different from zero"* - wrong, angular momentum is frame-dependent and any frame in which the free particle's trajectory does not pass through the origin is one where the particle has non-zero angular momentum. 2. Are you talking about *spin* or *orbital angular momentum* here? 3. What, exactly, do you mean by "imagine"? What constitutes, for instance, an imagination of the property of position or momentum in the quantum mechanical context for you?

Comment: I meant the orbital angular momentum which have an analogous in classical mechanics. My error is that I mismatch between the concept of trajectories and wave functions. But Please, You told me some thing that I couldn't grasp really. Free classical particle, could have a non zero of orbital angular momentum, how this could happen and how ?

Comment: Particles on hyperbolic (unbound) orbits have classical angular momentum and are free.

Comment: But these particles aren't fully free, hyperbolic orbit means the presence of an external force. I meant a fully free particle.

Comment: Any particle moving in a straight line that doesn't cross the origin has angular momentum.

Comment: The frame reference has to do with the angular momentum value, thank you, Now I grasped the idea that also a classical free particle could have any value of orbital angular momentum.  Thank you a lot.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as a "particle" in quantum physics. There are things that we can choose to interpret as waves or as particles or as some kind of composite, or something utterly different such as disturbances in the zero-point field (whatever that is).

The maths tells us that these elusive things have something that looks and behaves very like angular momentum, or "spin".

If you try to think classically about them, your head will be the one that ends up in a spin.

Comment: That's true, the concept of a wave function is the starting point to answer this, I think I miss match the concept of wave function and trajectory. In the quantum mechanical view, how the motion is cannot be answered. QM gives us the probability of presence in a such point of space, but how the particle travels from a point to another is some excluded in quantum mechanics because the notion of trajectory is not allowed. Thus, the particle could have any orbital angular momentum.